# Ubuntu live usb boot stuck on HP logo (Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows 10)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, boot, multi-boot

##### Background Info

I am dual booting Ubuntu 20.04 on an SSD with pre-installed Windows 10. This has been working for the past 2 months.

##### What happened first

I tried to boot Ubuntu and I got the same error as [this person](https://askubuntu.com/questions/697190/fsck-error-on-boot-dev-sda6-unexpected-inconsistency-run-fsck-manually)

I ran `fsck` on `/dev/sda3` and the problem was solved.

##### The current problem

A few hours later, I try to login to Ubuntu and I got an `Authentication Error` on the Home Screen. I restarted my computer and after selecting `Ubuntu`, the computer got stuck on the bright HP logo. While on the HP logo, I can access all the `tty`s, *but I can not login*.

##### What I think

I'm pretty sure this problem was caused by me running `fsck` on a mounted drive, but I'm not sure. It's probably something to do with corrupted passwords, too.

##### What I've tried

I have booted in recovery mode, tried resetting my password, and running commands. I know my password is correct. Some stack exchange answers say to run some commands in the `TTY`, but it always asks for my password and says `Incorrect password`.

Now I can't access my Linux files which has all my programming tools and projects.
Is there any way I can get my files back? Any help would be appreciated!

Tell me if you need more info!

Comment: You may follow the excellent answer bellow but it's also strongly recommended to update UEFI and, if available, the SSDs firmware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On occasion, I've seen some machines, HP in particular, seem to damage the *ext4* file system structure, *on internal SSD's, HDD's and on Live USB's*. Whatever the issue, it often is minor and can be fixed using *fsck* or using the *disks* application.

- Make a *new* [Ubuntu Live USB](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview), assuming the PC damaged the old one (you can reuse the USB device).
- Boot from the USB stick to *try Ubuntu*.
- Press <kbd>Super</kbd> (AKA "Windows" key), type *disk* and select the * [*Disks* utility](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/cloud-and-networking/9781800568525/6/ch06lvl1sec47/6-6-using-the-gnome-disks-utility).
- Click on each partition of the *SSD* (or *HDD*), click on the gear icon, and select *Repair Filesystem*.
- If the repair process finishes showing failure, *repeat it as above*. Though I cannot explain *why* two passes are often needed, it almost always succeeds on the *second* try.
- Keep that Live USB handy for the next time the *ext4* system is damaged.

Another thing to try, if that does not fix the issue, is to use the [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) utility, which can be downloaded and run from the Live USB. If you find this utility being used often, it can be permanently installed on a [Live USB with persistence](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230902/what-is-the-correct-way-to-create-a-persistent-ubuntu-20-04-usb).

Comment: Thank you so much! I still can't boot Ubuntu but I was able to `git commit` my projects.

Answer (score 0):

I spent more time than I care to admit troubleshooting a similar problem on an **HP TG01-2XXX**.

Adding acpi=off as a grub boot parameter allowed Ubuntu to start up while using a live USB successfully. Unfortunately, with acpi=off the live installer would have an error when creating the EFI partition. I could have done more troubleshooting and various permutations of ACPI and acpic settings (https://www.rigacci.org/wiki/doku.php/doc/appunti/linux/sa/irq_acpi_apic) I ultimately switched to Linux Mint - which is based off Ubuntu.

Linux Mint would boot and install fine with the acpi=off parameter. However, this caused other issues such as only one display working, non-responsive UI, and some inconsistent errors while booting and operating in the Mint environment.

With acpi=off I used Driver Manager to install the new Nvidia drivers and tried to boot the system using acpi=off. This did not work. After reading the log I was able to fix this and maintain Nvidia drivers by replacing acpi=off with noapic.

So if you are still struggling, I would suggest doing the following:

1. Switch to Linux Mint
2. Use onboard VGA port for initial boot and disable the Nvidia card
3. Boot live USB/CD with acpi=off and install
4. Boot the installed system with acpi=off
5. Update Nvidia drivers using Driver Manager
6. Restart and replace acpi=off with noapic

If all that fails or you want to continue trying Ubuntu, you may need to dig into drivers and ACPI and APIC options. Understanding what these options actually do did help be parse the error messages in a verbose boot setup (https://www.rigacci.org/wiki/doku.php/doc/appunti/linux/sa/irq_acpi_apic).

Answer (score -1):

SOLVED::::: I also had the same problem and managed to fix it. It has nothing to do with electricity in your computer. Just make sure the boot options match with the ones on your computers boot options.

On my case i had booted ubuntu in GPT with UEFI without CSM but on the computer my boot options were set to UEFI with CSM. The solution was for me to change my settings to UEFI without CSM in my computer

To do: power off your computer then power it on then press (f10) to go to bios settings and go to bios options and scroll down untill you find the legacy,UEFI WITHOUT CSM AND UEFI WITH CSM..switch to UEFI without CSM and restart your computer and it will be okay.

&)

Comment: I had already tried this and it did not work, the previous answer worked.